# How to reduce amount of array values in each iteration in array modifier?

Tags: modifiers

How to reduce amount  of array values in each iteration in array modifier?

what I mean:

let's say we have a cube with two array modifiers which gives us an array 5x5

what I need:

next array row on Z axis (3x3) right above previous,  and next (1x1). Is it possible to do with modifiers or drivers? How?
[image]

Comment: I think this is impossible ( using the modifier ) ,  you can use dupliverts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using the particle system set to Grid distribution :

[image]

- make a pyramid ( default cube with the top face resized )

[image]

- add a particle system to this pyramid :

[image]

- change the particle size / grid resolution /pyramid mesh  to get the desired results
- in the modifiers tab of the pyramid convert the particles to a real mesh :

[image]